# C++ concepts bug

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I'am front of a bug which causes gcc to crash. Actually it could be a bug in the Technical Specification, or just something that I should have known. This is why I ask the question.

It looks like at compilation time I can produce an unexpected recursive behaviour of the constraint checking performed inside a *requires expression* (ALTERNATIVE 1 inside the example). I can solve the problem by decomposing the *require expression* in conjunction of concepts (see ALTERNATIVE 2 inside the example). I use the fact that && operator does not perform the second test if the first was true.

Here is an example of code that causes my bug:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T> bool concept ValueGettable = requires(T a) { {a.value()}; };
template <class T> struct owner {
  T i;
  const T &value() const & { return i; }
};
///////////
template <class T> decltype(auto) get_value(T &&a) {
  return a;
}
template <ValueGettable T> decltype(auto) get_value(T &&a) {
  return a.value();
}
//////////// ALTERNATIVE 1  => causes gcc infinite looping until segfault
template <class T, class U>
bool concept ValueEqualComparable = requires(T a, U b) {
  requires ValueGettable<T> || ValueGettable<U>;
  { get_value(a) == get_value(b) }->bool;//if this line is removed the
                                         //the code compiles and run fine.

};
//////////// ALTERNATIVE 2 => works fine
//template <class T, class U> bool concept OrValueGettable = requires(T a, U b) {
//  requires ValueGettable<T> || ValueGettable<U>;
//};
//template <class T, class U> bool concept CompareEqualGot = requires(T a, U b) {
//  { get_value(a) == get_value(b) }
//  ->bool;
//};
//template <class T, class U>
//bool concept ValueEqualComparable =
//    OrValueGettable<T, U> &&CompareEqualGot<T, U>;
///////////////// END ALTERNATIVES

ValueEqualComparable { T, U }
bool operator==(const T &a, const U &b) { return get_value(a) == get_value(b); }

int main() {
  auto a = 0;
  auto b = owner<int>{0};
  a == b;
  std::vector<int> v;
  auto c = v.begin();
  auto d = owner<std::vector<int>::iterator>{v.begin()};
  c == d;   //if this line is removed the code 
            //compiles and run without error.
  return 0;
}
```

I know that the requirement inside *require expression* are evalutated as a cunjunction of requirement. So, I imagine that the problem is that even if a requirement fails, the succeeding requirement causes instantiations while in the conjunction case (ALTERNATIVE 2) this instantiations are not perfomed.

To my point of view this might a bug of the concept TS: It would be easier to implement concept as if the conjunctions were implemented as a succession of `if constexpr`, or may be this is already the case?

Nota: Whatever the answer, gcc 6.2 is bugged but I can not post the bug to buggzilla: I can not create an account.

Comment: Concept is in alpha in gcc ? report the bug. By the way, comment are not ASCII art "///////////"

Comment: I cannot report bugs, inscription to gcc bugzilla are closed. The way I made comments has no other goal than communication. I don't know why you see ASCII art here. You shall try to answer this question for you own good.